# Do not raise error for every conflict after specifying one preference with conflict_prefer()

Tags: r, conflict

I'm trying out the `conflicted` package in R to deal with common conflicts in function names that I run into.

However, once I've specified one preference, every single conflict raises an error.

For example, after specifying `conflict_prefer('select', 'dplyr')`, if I try to use the `filter` function from dplyr, I get:

```
> filter(mtcars, am == 1)
Error: [conflicted] `filter` found in 2 packages.
Either pick the one you want with `::` 
* dplyr::filter
* stats::filter
Or declare a preference with `conflict_prefer()`
* conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr")
* conflict_prefer("filter", "stats")
```

Is there any way to just default to the most recently loaded packages in instances of a conflict (the normal behavior), even after specifying a preference, rather than have *every* conflict raise an error after specifying just one preference?

Answer (score 0):

I can't read people's minds, but based on the [man page](https://rdrr.io/cran/conflicted/man/conflicted-package.html), it sounds like the package author intends to make you declare your preference every time.

The way the package author (and I) would recommend you permanently declare your preference is with assignment:

```
filter <- dplyr::filter
```

Personally, I just have gotten into the habit of typing out `dplyr::select` and `dplyr::filter` every time I use those functions.